# Filter WooCommerce archive pages by an additional category

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, actions, pre-get-posts

I'm working on a WooCommerce bookstore site with a custom `taxonomy.php` template that generates different archive pages based on a category called "Highlights". So, for example, there is a "Best Sellers" archive page that corresponds to `/books/product-category/highlights/best-sellers/`, producing a list of products assigned to the "Best Sellers" sub-category of "Highlights". On these archive pages, I'd like to include a filter than enables fine-tuning these product lists by a different category called "Topic" (normal WP category, not a custom taxonomy). To get things going, I've been trying to get a `$_GET` parameter working, such that `/highlights/best-sellers/?topic=art` would display Best Sellers of that category.

I initially tried using `pre_get_posts` to no avail, then attempted using the filter `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` a described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182661/filter-woocommerce-archive-pages-with-product-attribute-values-by-default). The function I've been trying, with various actions/filters is as follows, in `functions.php`:

```
function filter_product_topic($query) {

    if( is_admin() ) return;
    if( !$query->is_main_query() ) return;

    $tax_query = $query->get('tax_query');

    if( isset($_GET['topic']) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'       => 'topic',
            'field'   => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $_GET['topic'],
            'include_children'  => true,
            'operator'   => 'IN'
        );
    }

    $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
}
```

Basically, I ultimately want to selectively invoke this additional query parameter with the filters, to further refine the archive results. So, checking a box for "Art" would refine the archive results in this way. Does anyone know how I might be able to do so? Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add your `topic` to query_vars.

```
function so306156_add_query_vars_filter($vars)
{
    $vars[] = "topic";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'so306156_add_query_vars_filter');
```

and then, in `pre_get_posts`, you check for that var and act accordingly:

```
function so306156_manipulate_main_query($wp_query)
{
    if (function_exists('is_woocommerce') && !is_admin()) :
        if ($wp_query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce()) {
            if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['topic'])) {
                $tax_query = $query->get('tax_query');
                $tax_query[] = [
                    'taxonomy' => 'topic',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['topic'],
                    'include_children' => true, //true is default so you could leave that one out..
                    'operator' => 'IN' //also default
               ];
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'so306156_manipulate_main_query');
```

im not super sure about the `$wp_query->query_vars['topic']` thing in `terms`, try to echo that one out in the function aka `echo <pre>, print_r( $wp_query->query_vars['topic'] ), '</pre>';`

and now, i was thinking about another issue..
you created that custom taxonomy `topic` you are talking about, correct?? because you do not mention that part in your question. in your question you say, that `topic` is a sub-category of some sort..=?!$%/$%/(???? subcategory of product_cat?? than this stuff above won't work =)

Comment: thank you for the response- "topic" is not a custom taxonomy, rather a normal category in WP. I will try your approach and report back!

Comment: well if topic is not a custom taxonomy, than all this does not make much sense. or maybe it does, please try for yourself :D but first of all, your `tax_query` > `taxonomy` must be `product_cat` and NOT `topic`... topic is a `term` inside product_cat `taxonomy`...

Comment: Is there a different approach that would make more sense given that it's not a custom taxonomy? (I updated my question to specify that it's just a built-in category.)

Comment: its not built-in!! woocommerce products do have their own category taxonomy called product_cat!! but you could add your custom taxonomy and also apply it to products... alomst everything is possible ;)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I'm not as familiar w/ WooCommerce- I see that it is a Product Category.

Comment: One other, related question- it looks like the tax_query is working properly with the get parameter, but it seems to also be affecting another query I have going in a different part of the page- a hero slider also pulling products by category- is there a way to apply the pre_get_posts function *only* to the primary query in the archive listing?

Comment: of course, that part does this: `$wp_query->is_main_query()`